# Npm local dependency will generate a new package-lock.json with any install

Tags: javascript, npm, dependencies, npm-install

We have an old legacy app, and a relatively small package we wanted to integrate in it. To make the whole process with less overhead as possible, we decided to do that by installing the package from the repo itself.

For example, our structure looks like that:

```
- BigApp
  - SmallPackage
    - package.json
  - package.json
```

And so, the `BigApp` package.json has the following dependency:

`SmallPackage: "file:./SmallPackage"`

Now everything works great, up until we noticed that upon every `npm install` a new `package-lock.json` is created. That is an unwanted side effect since nothing has really changed.

I can't think of another reason for that but the fact that we used this local install path.

Can anywone come up with an idea why it happend?

Btw, I heard about `npm ci` - does it fit this scenario?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`package-lock.json` is generated by default in recent versions of `npm`. It is not because you are installing from a local path or anything like that.

If you don't want the benefits of a `package-lock.json` file, you can run `npm` with `--no-package-lock` or put `package-lock=false` in a `.npmrc` file in the project root. You can also delete `package-lock.json` or you can ignore it.

`npm ci` depends on `package-lock.json` or `npm-shrinkwrap.json`, so if you want to use `npm ci`, you probably want the `package-lock.json` file.